# Drop down doesn't show the values

Tags: sapui5

I've the following code and the problem is that the third column which is kids doesn't show the data in the drop down list/box,what am I missing here? 
I try to play with the fields path like add "\kName" but it doesnt work

the drop down should show the aaa and bbb...

```
var myData = {
        'Persons': [
            {
                'name': "Silke",
                'Age': "30",
                'kids': [
                    {
                        'kName': "aaa"

                 },

                    {
                        'kName': "bbb"
                 }


             ]

    }
    ]

    };

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    oModel.setData(myData);

    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

    var myTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();

    myTable.addColumn(

        new sap.ui.table.ColumnHeader({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label("label1", {
                text: "First name"
            }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
                value: "{name}"
            })

        })

    );

    myTable.addColumn(
        new sap.ui.table.ColumnHeader({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label("label2", {
                text: "Age"
            }),
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
                value: "{Age}"
            })

        })

    );


    var ddb = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({

        bindProperty: "/kName"
    });

    ddb.setModel(oModel);

    myTable.addColumn(

        new sap.ui.table.ColumnHeader({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label("label3", {
                text: "Kids"
            }),
            template:ddb

        })
    );



    myTable.bindRows("/Persons");

    myTable.placeAt("content");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DropdownBox` template should be defined as following:

```js
var ddb = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
    items: {
    path: "kids",
    template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
        text: "{kName}",
        key: "{kName}"
       })
    }
});
```